# nodejs child_process not work in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I wrote a code（phantomjs） used to crawl web content

```
    var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    t, address;

    if (system.args.length === 1) {
         phantom.exit(1);
    } 
    else {
        t = Date.now();
        address = system.args[1];
        page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
             /*console.log('FAIL to load the address');*/
        } else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log(/*'Page title is ' +*/ page.evaluate(function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
            var basee = document.createElement("base")
            basee.href = document.location.origin

            head.insertBefore(basee, head.firstChild);
            return document.head.innerHTML + document.body.innerHTML;
        }));
        /*console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');*/
    }
    phantom.exit();
  });
}
```

in Nodejs  I used the below code ， can return  page content，exit is 0

```
var _util=require("./util");

 _util.GetPageVisual("http://www.google.com").on("success",function(d){
    console.log(d);
})
.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log(err);

})
.on("exit",function(d){
    console.log('exit：' + d);
})
```

#### NOW I used this code in express ,it's not work , error event to be executed ，exit code  is -1

```
 exports.getPage = function (req, res) {
 params.page=req.params.url

_util.GetPageVisual(params.page)
    .on("success", function (d) {
        res.send(d);

    })
    .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("error":err);

    })
    .on("exit",function(d){
        console.log('子进程已退出，代码：' + d);
    })
/*getPage(params.page).on("success", function (d) {
 res.send(d);
 })
 */
```

};

Comment: could you show us the express code with the code you given above?

Comment: what is the *exact* error?